# Filter based on the output of a filter

Tags: haskell

I have a list of lists, e.g. `[[1,1,3],[1,2,4],[4,4,4],[5,6,7]]`

I want to remove all lists with duplicate elements, returning e.g. `[[1,2,4],[5,6,7]]`

My current problem is in creating a predicate for my application of `filter`.
I'm currently attempting to test the length of a filtered list against expected length of that list. However, I'm struggling to get it to work as a function on the elements of `list`.

```
removeLoops :: [[Integer]] -> Integer -> [[Integer]]
removeLoops list vs = filter (genericLength(filter (==)) < vs) list
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree? Or just a misunderstanding of predicates?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing here. Is your condition for having duplicates is that the length of a list after removing duplicates decreases? Note that `filter (==)` does not remove duplicates. There is a function `nub` for that. Although checking if a list has duplicates is easier then removing them. You should not use the latter to do the former, for better efficiency.

Comment: Are the sub-lists always sorted? If so, you can check for duplicates with `hasDups xs = or $ zipWith (==) xs (tail xs)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution is simpler than you think. You could filter your list with a predicate that tests whether a given list has duplicates:

```
ls = [[1,1,3],[1,2,4],[4,4,4],[5,6,7]]
filtered = filter hasNoDuplicates ls
```

Then all that remains is to find a suitable predicate. In this instance, the `nub` function comes in handy. This function takes a list, and returns that list without duplicates. So you could say:

```
import Data.List (nub)

hasNoDuplicates l = l == nub l
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

removeListsWithDuplicates ues a helper hasDuplicates to filter the list of lists. Simple.

```
removeListsWithDuplicates :: [[Integer]] -> [[Integer]]
removeListsWithDuplicates ls = filter (not . hasDuplicates) ls
```

hasDuplicates. An empty list has no duplicates. A list with several elements only has duplicates if the first one is repeated in the rest of the list or if the rest of the list has some other duplicates.

```
hasDuplicates :: [Integer] -> Bool
hasDuplicates [] = False
hasDuplicates (x:xs) = any (==x) xs || hasDuplicates xs
```